# How to run the "OSM Map Tile Packager"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, openstreetmap

I cloned this [repository](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid).
I need to run this project "OSM Map Tile Packager". I don't understand how to do that.

How tp run the "OSM Map Tile Packager"?

I'm using IDE Android Studio.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/OSMMapTilePackager#how-do-i-use-this

> Open a command line/terminal/bash shell

```
java -jar osmdroid-packager-<VERSION>-jar-with-dependencies.jar -u url -t <MapSourceName> -d <outputfile.zip> -zmin <MIN ZOOM> -zmax <MAX ZOOM up to 22> -n <NORTH> -s <SOUTH> -e <EAST> -w <WEST> -nthreads <optional, number of current threads, default 2> -fa <optional file extension add on, not really needed>1
```

> All bounds are in decimal degrees latitude/longitude.